# How do I display list of objects from Firebase in React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have retrieved data from my Firebase-database, and displayed it correctly earlier using a map function. [This is the list of objects retrieved correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7t39.png)

This time I tried to retrieve the sorted list using orderbychild, and I tried to map over the list, but it wont enter the map function. [I have console logged the state which says what shows this in the picture. It seems to be and empty list, but it still has objects inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjX9N.png)

Here is the file: https://pastebin.com/RLJMpzWN

[Here is the Firebase setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqNhU.png)

My question is, how do I display my list of objects?

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';




export default class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      highScoreList: null,
      isDataLoaded: false
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    const hList = [];
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('users')
    ref.orderByChild('hours').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      hList.push({
        id: snapshot.key,
        hours: snapshot.val().hours,
        name: snapshot.val().name
      });
    });

    this.setState({
      highScoreList: hList,
      isDataLoaded: true
    })



  }



  render(){
    if(this.state.isDataLoaded && this.state.highScoreList){

      return (
        <View style={styles.card}>
          {this.state.highScoreList.map( user => <Text key = {user.key} style = {{textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 10}}>{user.name}        {user.hours}</Text>)}
        </View>
      )
    }else{
      console.log("State var tom")
      return (<Text> Waiting for data</Text>)
    }
  }

}




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
    minHeight: 333
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
    marginBottom: 20,
    color: "black",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Simen96 I would recommend you to refactor your component to something like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      highScoreList: [],
      isDataLoaded: false
    }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('users')

    ref.orderByChild('hours').on('child_added', snapshot => {
      this.state.highScoreList.push({
        id: snapshot.key,
        hours: snapshot.val().hours,
        name: snapshot.val().name
      });
    });
  }

render(){
    if(this.state.highScoreList.length){

      return (
        <View style={styles.card}>
          {this.state.highScoreList.map( user => <Text key = {user.key} style = {{textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 10}}>{user.name}        {user.hours}</Text>)}
        </View>
      )
    }else{
      console.log("State var tom")
      return (<Text> Waiting for data</Text>)
    }
  }
```

The function componentDidMount and the 'child_added' callback will not execute sequentially because 'child_added' callback is asynchronous and setState will not wait for this callback to be triggered.

Comment: I changed it, but I'm getting an error cannot read property 'highScoreList' of undefined, I think its the if statement in render. I also console logged the "this.state.highScoreList" above the if statement, and the state (list) is empty.

Comment: I updated my answer, use an arrow function on the 'child_added' callback, to bind the `this` context from the upper scope

Comment: Thanks for helping, but unfortunately I'm getting "Waiting for Data" which means it did not enter the if statement at all. And also console logging above the if statement gives me this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjX9N.png

Comment: If you do console.log(this.state.highScoreList.length) what does it return?

Comment: console.log(this.state)
console.log("length" + this.state.highScoreList.length) in render() above the if statement gives this:
https://imgur.com/a/iBGJrrm

Comment: It seems the highscorelist state is an array(0) with 1 other object called highscorelist as well, which contains the 3 object i want to access. This makes me think there is something wrong with the render method maybe.

Comment: @AndréFatia I'm pretty sure you shouldn't mutate the state like this.